# Label text and number

Tags: vb.net

I have a lavel which displays some numbers being multiplied. However, I can't figure out how to insert text after the numbers. This could be the numbers multiplied followed by the text "minutes"

```
Label1.Text = Math.Round((Single.Parse(TextBox2.Text)) / (Single.Parse(TextBox1.Text) * 19.5 + 475), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.Round(...).ToString() & " minutes"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use concatenation. something like this:

```
Label1.Text = (Math.Round((Single.Parse(TextBox2.Text)) / (Single.Parse(TextBox1.Text) * 19.5 + 475), 1)) & " minutes"
```

Hope this helps. Goodluck. :)